# insert variable in array php foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i have a function with a dynamic array.

```
function doIt($accountid,$targeting){
    $post_url= "https://url".$accountid."/";
    $fields = array(
          'name' => "test",
          'status'=> "PAUSED",
          'targeting' => array(
            $targeting
          ),
      ); 
   $curlreturn=curl($post_url,$fields);
};
```

And i want to build the array "$fields" dynamically within a foreach loop. Like that:

```
$accountid="57865";    
$targeting=array(
                      "'device_platforms' => array('desktop'),'interests' => array(array('id' => '435345','name' => 'test')),",
                      "'device_platforms' => array('mobile'), 'interests' => array(array('id' => '345345','name' => 'test2')),",
                    );

foreach ($targeting as $i => $value) {
        doit($accountid,$value);
    }
```

The Problem is, that the array within the function will not be correctly filled. If i output the array in the function i get something like:

```
....[0] => array('device_platforms' => array('desktop'),'custom_audiences'=> ['id' => '356346']), )
```

The beginning [0] should be the problem. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: In this `foreach ($targeting as $i => $value) {
        doit($accountid,$value);
    }` how you are getting `$accountid`?

Comment: good question. its defined before the foreach. isn't it global then? I'll update the main post.

Comment: can you share your expected output?

Comment: output should be: ... [status] => PAUSED  [targeting] => Array ([device_platforms] => Array([0] => desktop) [interests] => Array(Array([id]=> 435345 [name] => test))

Comment: actually it's: [status] => PAUSED  [targeting] => Array ([0] => 'device_platforms' => array('desktop'),'custom_audiences'=> ['id' => '435345'])...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out. The problem was the way you are defining `$targeting` array. You can't have multiple keys with same name

**Change 1:**

```
$targeting = array(
array(
    'device_platforms' => array('desktop'),
    'interests' => array(
        array('id' => '435345', 
            'name' => 'test')),
    ),
array(
    'device_platforms' => array('mobile'),
    'interests' => array(
        array('id' => '345345', 
            'name' => 'test2'))
    )
);
```

**Change 2:**

```
$fields = array(
        'name' => "test",
        'status' => "PAUSED",
        'targeting' => $targeting //removed array
    );
```

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785436) `this will just print postfields`

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function doIt($accountid, $targeting)
{
    $post_url = "https://url" . $accountid . "/";
    $fields = array(
        'name' => "test",
        'status' => "PAUSED",
        'targeting' => $targeting
    );
    print_r($fields);
}

$accountid = "57865";
$targeting = array(
    array(
        'device_platforms' => array('desktop'),
        'interests' => array(
            array('id' => '435345', 
                'name' => 'test')),
        ),
    array(
        'device_platforms' => array('mobile'),
        'interests' => array(
            array('id' => '345345', 
                'name' => 'test2'))
        )
);
foreach ($targeting as $i => $value)
{
    doit($accountid, $value);
}
```

Comment: looks much better, but i still have the leading [0] in the $fields.  [0] => Array ( [device_platforms] => Array ( [0] => desktop ) [interests] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] =>.... should be  [device_platforms] => Array ( [0] => desktop ) [interests] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => ...

Comment: change `"'device_platforms` to `'device_platforms`  look at Sahils answer, he removed the doublequotes.

Comment: @Holger: Within the array definition. Can't find a " 'device_platforms where i can leave ". i've tried to change ' to ". makes no difference.

Comment: @swapfile In you comment you have mentioned output should be `[status] => PAUSED [targeting] => Array ([device_platforms] => Array([0] => desktop) [interests] => Array(Array([id]=> 435345 [name] => test)) ` thats what i did

Comment: Your code is: `$targeting=array("'device_platforms' => array('desktop'),'intere....",` but it has to be: `$targeting=array('device_platforms' => array('desktop'),'intere......,`

Comment: @Holger Is your last comment is for me?

Comment: @Sahil sorry, yes it's for you

Comment: @SahilGulati: ok i think the problem is that i have 'targeting' => array(
            $targeting
          ), and you 'targeting' => $targeting but i need more variables within targeting. I try to define the whole variables needed in 'targeting" within $targeting. Then i hope it'll work.

Comment: @swapfile Yes , thats the changes which i have done , in my post, i Hope it will be working fine now..If you have any doubts then go through the demo url which i have pasted in my post